# SQL Server Query using results from table to Call function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem with SQL Server. I have a table with machine statements, and another one with production data. The time between both tables are not the same to get the corresponding data. I don't know how to Join these tables. Also, I need to filter just the code 17 from Table A.

For example:

**Table a**:

```
Machine  Code  Time
----------------------------------
EPSX     17    2018-08-28 12:09:32
EPSA     19    2018-08-28 12:09:39
EPSC     17    2018-08-28 11:10:58
```

**Table b**:

```
Machine  Waste(meters)  Time
-------------------------------------------
EPSX     57m            2018-08-28 12:09:38
EPSA     128m           2018-08-28 12:09:43
EPSC     12m            2018-08-28 11:11:02
```

Desired output:

```
Machine  Code  Waste(meters)
----------------------------
EPSX     17    57m
EPSC     17    12m
```

I'm thinking to get the relation with the following statement:

```
a.Machine = b.machine (this is easy)
AND a.Time > b.Time 
AND a.Time <= DATEADD(MINUTE, 2, b.Time)
```

How can I solve this? Maybe using function? I can get the correct directly from the function from table b. But can I call the Table a and use a.Time in function call?

Comment: Why can't you just ignore `Time` completely?  You don't need to use it at all to get the result you want from the sample data.

Comment: WHERE a.Code = 17?

Comment: No matter what you do you run the risk of joining rows that don't really belong together. This is because the design of the data is not solid enough to allow accurate joins. This is going to be mostly correct most of the time at best.

Comment: I really need to Join these tables, to get the Waste that was related to the Code I have in Machine. But the waste time is launched by the machine a few seconds or sometimes Minutes(Never greater than 1 minute) after the machine Stop. At same time, I have a lot of other events from the machine and I need to look only at the Code 17. It was just one example. And I also can't ignore Time, because it's a long list of events, so I need to consider the time with an "Offset".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time in table `a` for `EPSX`  is `2018-08-28 12:09:32`, in table `b` `2018-08-28 12:09:38`, i.e. `a.time < b.time`, but you are testing `a.Time > b.Time AND a.Time <= DATEADD(MINUTE, 2, b.Time)`. This cannot work. Change it to

```
a.time BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -2, b.Time) AND b.time
```

or you can turn it around and test

```
b.time BETWEEN a.time AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 2, a.Time)
```

Together

```
SELECT a.Machine, a.Code, b.[Waste(meters)]
FROM
    a
    INNER JOIN b
        ON a.Machine = b.Machine AND
           b.time BETWEEN a.time AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 2, a.Time)
WHERE
    a.Code = 17
```

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoRogenski Just be aware of the potential for this to match on multiple rows within the narrow window of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the time stamps are always only out by a little bit then you could round the times to the nearest minute (google it) and use the rounded time as your FK between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from tableA a cross apply (
    select top 1 waste from tableB b
    where b.Machine = a.Machine and b.Time >= a.Time
    order by b.Time
) c
where a.Machine = 17;
```

I generally try to avoid `top` but I'll go ahead and offer it as an easy solution.